# R: sort letters in a string vector in alphabetical case sensitive order

Tags: r, string, alphanumeric

I have the following column "Names" in my dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
VecA<-c("A","a")      
c<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(VecA,VecA))%>%
mutate(Names=paste(.$Var1,.$Var2,.$Var3,.$Var4,sep=""))%>%
select(Names)
> c
  Names
1    AA
2    aA
3    Aa
4    aa
```

There are 4 values as a result of the combination of `VecA` I would like to order every letter of every Name so that at the end I only have three distinct names left such as `c("AA","Aa","aa)`. That means that "aA" and "Aa" are the same. 
Can this be achieved?

**Edit:**
The below posted answers do what I asked for but I am unfortunately not able to use them for my larger strings.
Suppose

```
VecA<-c("A","a")
VecB<-c("B","b")
c<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(VecA,VecA,VecB,VecB))%>%mutate(Names=paste(.$Var1,.$Var2,.$Var3,.$Var4,sep=""))%>%select(Names)
```

With the answer posted by @NicE
I get

```
c$Names2<-sapply(c$Names,function(x)paste0(sort(unlist(strsplit(x,"")),decreasing=T),collapse=""))
c
   Names Names2
1   AABB   BBAA
2   aABB   BBAa
3   AaBB   BBAa
4   aaBB   BBaa
5   AAbB   BbAA
6   aAbB   BbAa
7   AabB   BbAa
8   aabB   Bbaa
9   AABb   BbAA
10  aABb   BbAa
11  AaBb   BbAa
12  aaBb   Bbaa
13  AAbb   bbAA
14  aAbb   bbAa
15  Aabb   bbAa
16  aabb   bbaa
```

However, I need them in the order `AABB,AaBB,AaBB,aaBB,AABb` and so on.
With deleting the duplicated values afterwards like this I get another problem.

```
c <- data.frame(names=apply(expand.grid(VecA,VecA,VecB,VecB), 1, paste, collapse=""), stringsAsFactors=F)
c[!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(c$names, ""), sort), fromLast = T),, drop=F]

   names
1   AABB
3   AaBB
4   aaBB
9   AABb
11  AaBb
12  aaBb
13  AAbb
15  Aabb
16  aabb
```

The problem in this case is that the duplicated rows are deleted. What I need in that case is a second row indicating the sum of the values if there would be a column with data associated to each of the originally 16 rows. So an advanced example could look like:

```
VecA<-c("A","a")
VecB<-c("B","b")
c<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(VecA,VecA,VecB,VecB))%>%mutate(Names=paste(.$Var1,.$Var2,.$Var3,.$Var4,sep=""))%>%select(Names)%>%mutate(Value=runif(NROW(.),1,100))
c
   Names    Value
1   AABB 69.19903
2   aABB 28.75896
3   AaBB 61.45903
4   aaBB 78.43504
5   AAbB 28.58105
6   aAbB 41.33014
7   AabB 29.75036
8   aabB 77.41428
9   AABb 85.59857
10  aABb 61.20740
11  AaBb 57.77745
12  aaBb 89.71112
13  AAbb 11.68326
14  aAbb 30.67187
15  Aabb 48.28885
16  aabb 44.82100
```

With the answer provided by @NicE I am able to summarize the data myself however, The ordering needs to be slightly different as mentioned above. Is that possible? Sorry for not posting this entire set at the beginning I thought I will figure it out myself once I get the strings in the right order.

Comment: I'm guessing names have multiple characters etc. If you have bA, what should be the result?

Comment: I added the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sapply(c$Names,function(x)paste0(sort(unlist(strsplit(x,"")),decreasing=T),collapse=""))
```

It breaks up the strings to character vectors, orders them and pastes them back together.